# Store multiple hex values in a string c++

Tags: c++

I want to convert an array of integers into hex form, then concatenate all off the hex values into one C++ string. The integers were originally `uint8_t`, but I read about how to convert them to `int` with no problem. So far, I have this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < HASHLEN; ++i) {
  int a = static_cast< int >(hash2[i]); // convert the uint8_t to a int
  cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << a; // print the hex value with the leading zero (important)
}
```

This code prints the hex value of every int in the array on one line, like this:

`41a9ffb9588717989367b3ec942233d5d9a982f8658c1073a87262da43fd42c9`

How can I store this value as a string? I tried creating a `string hash = "";` before the loop and using this line:

`hash = hash + to_string(setfill('0') + setw(2) + hex + a);`

instead of the `cout` line, but this does not work. If you're wondering, the error is

`error: invalid operands to binary expression ('__iom_t4<char>' and 'std::__1::__iom_t6')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacing `cout` with [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) will do the job:

```
std::stringstream hexstr;
for (int i = 0; i < HASHLEN; ++i) {
    int a = static_cast< int >(hash2[i]);
    hexstr << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << a;
}
std::string res = hexstr.str();
```